# How to send SOAP request with spring boot, when there is no request object defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I am trying to create a client to send a SOAP request with spring boot to the wsdl defined bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<definitions xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="urn:ATMWebSvr" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:ATMWebSvr">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"
>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
 <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />
 <xsd:complexType name="ErroProcesso">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Codigo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Descricao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="ValorEsperado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="ValorInformado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="ErrosProcesso">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Erro" type="tns:ErroProcesso" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="DadosSeguro">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="NumeroAverbacao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="CNPJSeguradora" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="NomeSeguradora" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="NumApolice" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="TpMov" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="TpDDR" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="ValorAverbado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="RamoAverbado" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="SuccessProcesso">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="dhAverbacao" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Protocolo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="DadosSeguro" type="tns:DadosSeguro" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="SuccessProcessoMDFe">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="dhChancela" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Protocolo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="InfoProcesso">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Codigo" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Descricao" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="InfosProcesso">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Info" type="tns:InfoProcesso" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="Retorno">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Numero" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Serie" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Filial" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="CNPJCli" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="TpDoc" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="InfAdic" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Erros" type="tns:ErrosProcesso" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Averbado" type="tns:SuccessProcesso" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Infos" type="tns:InfosProcesso" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="RetornoMDFe">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="Numero" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Serie" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Filial" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Erros" type="tns:ErrosProcesso" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Declarado" type="tns:SuccessProcessoMDFe" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
   <xsd:element name="Infos" type="tns:InfosProcesso" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="averbaCTeRequest">
  <part name="usuario" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="senha" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="codatm" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="xmlCTe" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="averbaCTeResponse">
  <part name="Response" type="tns:Retorno" /></message>
<message name="averbaNFeRequest">
  <part name="usuario" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="senha" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="codatm" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="xmlNFe" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="averbaNFeResponse">
  <part name="Response" type="tns:Retorno" /></message>
<message name="declaraMDFeRequest">
  <part name="usuario" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="senha" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="codatm" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="xmlMDFe" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="declaraMDFeResponse">
  <part name="Response" type="tns:RetornoMDFe" /></message>
<message name="AddBackMailRequest">
  <part name="usuario" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="senha" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="codatm" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="aplicacao" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="assunto" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="remetentes" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="destinatarios" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="corpo" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="chave" type="xsd:string" />
  <part name="chaveresp" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<message name="AddBackMailResponse">
  <part name="return" type="xsd:string" /></message>
<portType name="ATMWebSvrPortType">
  <operation name="averbaCTe">
    <documentation>Interface de averbação eletrônica AT&amp;M para CTe</documentation>
    <input message="tns:averbaCTeRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:averbaCTeResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="averbaNFe">
    <documentation>Interface de averbação eletrônica AT&amp;M para NFe</documentation>
    <input message="tns:averbaNFeRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:averbaNFeResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="declaraMDFe">
    <documentation>Interface de declaração do MDFe para AT&amp;M</documentation>
    <input message="tns:declaraMDFeRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:declaraMDFeResponse"/>
  </operation>
  <operation name="AddBackMail">
    <documentation>Serviço de envio de emails para aplicações automatizadas</documentation>
    <input message="tns:AddBackMailRequest"/>
    <output message="tns:AddBackMailResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ATMWebSvrBinding" type="tns:ATMWebSvrPortType">
  <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <operation name="averbaCTe">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ATMWebSvr#averbaCTe" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="averbaNFe">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ATMWebSvr#averbaNFe" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="declaraMDFe">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ATMWebSvr#declaraMDFe" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></output>
  </operation>
  <operation name="AddBackMail">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:ATMWebSvr#AddBackMail" style="rpc"/>
    <input><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></input>
    <output><soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:ATMWebSvr"/></output>
  </operation>
</binding>
<service name="ATMWebSvr">
  <port name="ATMWebSvrPort" binding="tns:ATMWebSvrBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://webserver.averba.com.br/20/index.soap"/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

The thing is, when I generate the classes using JAXB there is not bean for the request objects (I am trying to use the averbaCTeRequest). Now, using soapUI I can use the service normally, I am just having a hard time to code this in spring boot. Should I not be using objects? Should I be building this message differently? And on top of that, how do I specify the action "averbaCte" on my request?.

```
@Configuration
public class AtmIntegracaoConfiguration {

    @Value("${atm.url}")
    private String url;

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("atm.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public AtmIntegracaoClient atmIntegracaoClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        AtmIntegracaoClient client = new AtmIntegracaoClient();
        client.setDefaultUri(url);

        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
            client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

        return client;
    }
}



public class AtmIntegracaoClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AtmIntegracaoClient.class);

    @Value("${atm.usuario}")
    private String usuario;

    @Value("${atm.senha}")
    private String senha;

    @Value("${atm.codatm}")
    private String codatm;

    @Value("${atm.url}")
    private String url;

    public Retorno averbaCte(String cteXmlStr) {


        Retorno response = (Retorno) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive("http://homologaws.averba.com.br/20/index.soap", request,
                        new SoapActionCallback(
                                "http://localhost:8080/ATMWebSvr/averbaCTe"));

        return response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. The problem was that this SOAP service is RPC style and I am guessing a bit old. The trick for me was instead of using JAXb to use wsimport.

Just run:

```
wsimport -keep {wsdl url}
```

It will generate the objects, an interface for the service and a service implementation.

Comment: Can you share an example how you have done that with Spring Boot? Like a github or something? I have the same use case and maven-jaxb2-plugin is not generating the classes for me